# Crash detection, logging, and C++

Tags: c++, qt, crash

I have an application that I wrote in QT C++, it runs fine under Ubuntu for me, both in a Virtual Box, and on the "target machine", a little Zotac MAG box. I have run it for hours, pumped input through it (mind numbing work), and I can't get the bastard to crash, but users keep telling me that it crashes maybe 4 times per day. The app doesn't really do much, it's an HTML5 app, just a webkit widget that loads a website. There are one or two places where it might crash, and I've gone through the code and it looks fine and it works for me.

The crash reports I get are second hand, through a translator, where both of the people have no clue, the extent of the details are: "It crashes alot." Obviously that's about as useful as balls on a priest when it comes to finding out what the real issue is. Now it could be bad ram, it could be some misconfiguration, and that's gonna be checked, but what I would like to add is two things:

Logging and Crash detection.

I have a handle on logging, I am pretty sure that's not going to be a terrible issue, but I am not sure how to go about Crash detection, and maybe even have an automatic submission of the log.

How would I go about this? Any recommendations that could ease the learning curve would be awesome.

The deployment system is Ubuntu 10.10 LTS.

Comment: Can you get core files back from the crashes? Alternatively Firefox on Windows has a built-in crash reporting mechanism - I'd expect the Linux one does too so you might be able to borrow that?

Comment: Do you distribute your code by source or by binary?  If the latter, I suspect different versions of the runtime libraries are present on the other users' machines. Have your users run "ldd yourapp" (where yourapp is the name of the executable binary).  Does the list of their runtime linker dependencies match yours?  Have you suggested to your customers to enable core dumps and provide you back the dump file?  (Search SO for how to enable core dumps).

Comment: It's a binary distribution of a QT C++ app, the source code is not yet available, but will be soon, it's not much sc. Unfortunately, the app doesn't target tech savy people, they phear cmdline stuff. As it turned out, the reasons for the crash were hardware related, but I'd still like to try this core dump files and eventually breakpad. Thanks for all these suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [Google's Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) is what you're looking for.